# Deploy SSIS Package to SQL Server Agent 2014

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio-2013, ssis, sql-server-2014

I have been working on this for literally hours and hours. I have created an SSIS package in Visual Studio 2013 Professional that executes without errors. The package effectively reads an excel file and inserts and updates an SQL Table. I would like to schedule this package as a job in the SQL Server Agent.

What I am stuck with is how to exactly do that. I'm confused with the whole converting to 'Package Deployment Model' (which also generates an error if I have any existing connection managers) which some sites suggest amongst many other alternatives like using Integration Catalogs.

I have two connection managers, one that feeds from an underlying excel sheet and the other reads from an SQL Database table. Does anyone have a procedure I can follow, I'am literally stuck. I haven't been able to find a concise explanation for this.

Here is a screenshot of the workflow:

[image]

Comment: There are already a lot of articles on the web about how to schedule a package in a job.   Can you be more specific about where you are stuck?

Comment: @Greg you need to read up on the differences between package and project deployment [link](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-2012-projects-deployment-configurations-and-monitoring/) and choose one that best suits your needs. For excel to work you will also need to install the appropriate excel (ACE) drivers [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255). Similarly if you have additional drivers for the 'SQL source' then these would need to be installed.